# get id from url security

Tags: php, mysql, get

I'm creating a basic blog and I'm using the following code.

It's collecting the id (always a number) from the url and before I use, I wondered if anyone could check the security of the code and let me know if its ok?

I really don't want any injections, etc, and I want to keep it as much secured as possible.

```
<?php
    if(is_numeric($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] > 0){

        include("connectionfile.php");

        $ia = intval($_GET['id']);
        $ib = mysql_real_escape_string($ia);
        $ic = strip_tags($ib);

        $qProfile = "SELECT * FROM #### WHERE id='$ic'  ";
        $rsProfile = mysql_query($qProfile);
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($rsProfile);
        extract($row);
        $title = trim($title);
        $post = trim($post);
        $date = trim($date);
        mysql_close();
    }else{
       echo 'hack error here';
    }
?>
```

Comment: [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Also, the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated in favour of the PDO or MySQLi extensions.

Comment: thanks all for your help, can anyone give an example of a PDO that does the same thing as above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ia = intval($_GET['id']);
$ib = mysql_real_escape_string($ia);
$ic = strip_tags($ib);
```

`strip_tags` is useless, because it is only relevant in an HTML context. Any one of the other two methods would be sufficient to prevent SQL injection. Generally, just use the appropriate escaping mechanism for the language you're dealing with. In this case you're dealing with SQL, so `mysql_real_escape_string` alone is fine. See [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/) for a step-by-step approach to escaping.

Better yet, learn PDO with prepared statements instead of the deprecated `mysql_` functions, which solves the issue of SQL injection much better.

Comment: hi thanks for your feedback, would you be able to give an example of PDO, done a bit of reading on it but bit confusing!

Comment: There's an example at the end of the linked article.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use `mysql_` functions.  They are deprecated.  Use mysqli or
   PDO.
2. Use *parameterized queries*
3. Don't use "extract" as it pollutes the local scope.  There are rare cases where it's safe, usually internal to an ORM, where it's
   within the object.  This is dangerous otherwise as all forms of
   nasty variable names could be introduced, especially with successful
   SQL injection.
4. Do exception handling so that database errors do not break the page entirely, and in the case of a bad query somehow forced via SQL Injection, nothing is displayed to indicate that the query was broken.
5. Even after you do all the above, still make sure you use `htmlentities()` or otherwise validate the data is what you expect before you display.

Answer (score 0):

This code is a mess ;-)

1. if statement can be simplified "if (($id = (int)$_GET['id']) > 0) {"
2. if you acknowledge my 1. point, then $ia, $ib and $ic can be deleted
3. don't trim() database data! data should be trimed before INSERT into database.
4. read what @FilmJ has answered you